# Colocar arquivos dentro de um arquivo .zip

Tags: java, arquivo-zip

Tenho uma classe onde faço a compactação de alguns arquivos:

```
public class CompactarArquivo {

    //Constante
    static final int TAMANHO_BUFFER = 4096; // 4kb

    //método para compactar arquivo
    public static void compactarParaZip(String arqSaida, String arqEntrada, String arqEntrada1)
            throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream destino;
        ZipOutputStream saida;

        try {
            destino = new FileOutputStream(new File(arqSaida));
            saida = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(destino));

            add(arqEntrada, saida);
            add(arqEntrada1, saida); 

            saida.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void add(String arquivo, ZipOutputStream saida) throws IOException {
        int cont;
        byte[] dados = new byte[TAMANHO_BUFFER];

        File file = new File(arquivo);
        BufferedInputStream origem = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), TAMANHO_BUFFER);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
        saida.putNextEntry(entry);

        while ((cont = origem.read(dados, 0, TAMANHO_BUFFER)) != -1) {
            saida.write(dados, 0, cont);
        }

        origem.close();
    }
```

Nessa classe eu pego dois arquivos e gero um `.zip`. Porém gostaria de abrir esse arquivo `.zip` posteriormente e adicionar mais arquivos dentro dele. Como resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando uma versão anterior ao Java 7, a melhor maneira de fazer isso é descompactar os arquivos dentro do **.zip** atual e jogar junto com os novos arquivos em um novo **.zip**.

Baseado [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305091/4190610).

```
private static void addFilesToZip(File source, File[] files, String path){
    try{
        File tmpZip = File.createTempFile(source.getName(), null);
        tmpZip.delete();

        if(!source.renameTo(tmpZip)){
            throw new Exception("Não foi possível criar o arquivo temporário (" + source.getName() + ")");
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[TAMANHO_BUFFER];
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmpZip));
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(source));

        for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path + files[i].getName()));                
            for(int read = in.read(buffer); read > -1; read = in.read(buffer)){
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }                
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }

        for(ZipEntry ze = zin.getNextEntry(); ze != null; ze = zin.getNextEntry()){
            if(!zipEntryMatch(ze.getName(), files, path)){
                out.putNextEntry(ze);
                for(int read = zin.read(buffer); read > -1; read = zin.read(buffer)){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                out.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        out.close();
        tmpZip.delete();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static boolean zipEntryMatch(String zeName, File[] files, String path){
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if((path + files[i].getName()).equals(zeName)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Esse segundo método verifica se já não existe nenhum arquivo com o mesmo nome dentro do **Zip**. Obviamente isso precisa ser melhorado, mas já é um bom ponto de partida.

Se você estiver usando Java 7. Você pode usar a biblioteca *java.nio* e fazer dessa forma (Exemplo retirado [daqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html))

```
private static void addNoZipExistente(String arqZip, String arqInserir, String nomeArquivoNoZip){       
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
    env.put("create", "true");

    URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + "file:/" + arqZip.replace("\\", "/"));

    try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) 
    {
        Path arquivoParaInserir = Paths.get(arqInserir);
        Path localNoZip = zipfs.getPath(nomeArquivoNoZip);      

        Files.copy(arquivoParaInserir, localNoZip, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ); 
    }catch(IOException ioex){
        //Tratar o erro
    }
}
```

---

Fora isso, eu também mudaria a forma que recebes os parâmetros no método `compactarParaZip()`, para que ele possa receber múltiplos parâmetros. Talvez tu só precises de dois, mas isso deixa o método mais dinâmico.

```
public static void compactarParaZip(String arqSaida, String... entradas) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream destino;
    ZipOutputStream saida;

    try {
        destino = new FileOutputStream(new File(arqSaida));
        saida = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(destino));

        for(String arq : entradas){
            add(arq, saida);
        }

        saida.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Um exemplo de como usar, seria

```
compactarParaZip("novoArquivo.zip", "arq1.txt", "arq2.txt", "arq3.txt");
// posso colocar quantos parâmetros quiser
```

Comment: As duas respostas resolveriam o problema, porém escolhi a do @jbueno pois está mais completa e explicativa.

Answer (score 3):

Achei um tutorial em Inglês e fiz a tradução e o teste dele.
Para inserir arquivos dentro de um arquivo ZIP você deve usar a biblioteca NIO, presente no Java 7 ou superior.

```
    Map<String, String> zip_properties = new HashMap<>();

    /* Se o arquivo ZIP já existe, coloque false*/
    zip_properties.put("create", "false");

    zip_properties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");

    Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\Arquivos.zip");

    /* Especifique o caminho para o arquivo zip que você quer ler como um sistema de arquivos */
    URI zip_disk = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());

     /* Cria o Sistema de arquivo ZIP */
    try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties)) {

        /* Cria o arquivo dentro do ZIP*/
        Path ZipFilePath = zipfs.getPath("footer.html");

        /* Caminho do arquivo que deve ser adicionado */
        Path addNewFile = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\footer.html");

        Files.copy(addNewFile, ZipFilePath);
    }
```

Antes da execução do código[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois da execução do código
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo .html que coloquei dentro do zip não foi corrompido.

Fonte: http://thinktibits.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/Add-Files-to-Existing-ZIP-Archive-in-Java-Example-Program.html